# How I can create advanced PHP link?

Tags: php

I want to create a PHP file with $_GET[] function like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/account.php?register  -> Register page
http://mywebsite.com/account.php?login -> Login page
```

It's like a $_GET[] but without variable...

Someone can explain this to me?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you're specifically trying to achieve? And perhaps show what you've already tried?

Comment: You are probably looking for mod_rewrite. Google will turn up a ton of guides/tutorials, but heres one to get you started http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Comment: I think he just wants to make the url look better. instead of ...?page=register he wants ...?register

Comment: you should use .htaccess

Comment: @redmoon7777 If I need to use .htaccess, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['register']))
```

The variable will be set, but with no value

Answer (score -1):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the raw query string.